# Split words and remove duplicates

Tags: c++

Okay I fixed the previous error. Thank you,  but now when I want to ask the user if they want to play again, I run the print menu function, but it skips over the "Enter a sentence" statement... Any ideas why? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void clearScreen();
void printMenu();
int main()
{
    //Variables 
    string s;
    char selection;
    string w;
    string buf;
    char select2;


    cout << "Enter a paragraph or a sentence : " ; //Get sentence 

    getline(cin, s);


    //Menu 
    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "                 Menu          " << endl;
    cout <<"        ------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "A -- Convert paragraph to all caps " << endl;
    cout << "B -- Convert paragraph to all lowercase " << endl;
    cout << "C -- Delete whitespaces " << endl;
    cout << "D -- Split words & remove duplicates " << endl;
    cout << "E -- Search a certain word " << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Please select one of the above: " ; //Get selection 
    cin >> selection;
    cout << "" << endl;
    stringstream ss(s);// Insert the string into a stream
    vector<string> tokens;// Create vector to hold words 
    switch (selection) //Switch statement
    {
        //If A is chose convert to uppercase 
        case 'a':
        case 'A': cout << "You chose to convert the paragraph to all uppercase" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  for(int i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
                    {
                        s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
                    }
                    cout << "This is it: " << s << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    cout <<"Would you like to try another? Y/N \n ";
                        cin >> select2;
                        clearScreen ();
                         if (select2 == 'Y' || select2 == 'y')
                          {
                             printMenu (); 
                             break;
                          }
                          else if (select2 != 'Y' || select2 != 'y')
                              exit(0);



        case 'b':
        case 'B':
                  //If B is chose convert to lowercase 
                  cout << "You chose to convert the paragragh to all lowercase" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  for (int i=0; s[i] !='\0'; i++)
                  {
                      s[i]=tolower(s[i]);
                  }
                    cout << "This is it: " << s << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    cout <<"Would you like to try another? Y/N \n ";
                        cin >> select2;
                        clearScreen ();
                         if (select2 == 'Y' || select2 == 'y')
                          {
                             printMenu (); 
                             break;
                          }
                          else if (select2 != 'Y' || select2 != 'y')
                              exit(0);

        case 'c':
        case 'C': 
                  //If C is chosen delete spaces 
                  cout << "You chose to delete the whitespaces in the paragraph" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
                    if(s[i] == ' ') s.erase(i,1);
                  cout <<"This is it: " << s << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  cout <<"Would you like to try another? Y/N \n ";
                        cin >> select2;
                        clearScreen ();
                         if (select2 == 'Y' || select2 == 'y')
                          {
                             printMenu (); 
                             break;
                          }
                          else if (select2 != 'Y' || select2 != 'y')
                              exit(0);
        case 'd':
        case 'D': 
                  //If D is chosen split words and remove duplicates 
                  cout << "You chose to split the words & remove the duplicates in the paragraph" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;

                  while (ss >> buf)
                  {
                    if(find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), buf) == tokens.end())
                    tokens.push_back(buf);
                  }
                  cout << "This is it: " << endl;
                  for (vector<string>::iterator it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it)
                  cout << "- " << *it << " " << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;


                  cout << "" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  cout <<"Would you like to try another? Y/N \n ";
                        cin >> select2;
                        clearScreen ();
                         if (select2 == 'Y' || select2 == 'y')
                          {
                             printMenu (); 
                             break;
                          }
                          else if (select2 != 'Y' || select2 != 'y')
                              exit(0);





        case 'e':
        case 'E': 
                  //If E is chosen allow the user to search for a word 
                  cout << "You chose to search for a certain word in the paragraph. " << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  cout << "Enter the word you want to search for: ";
                  cin >> w;
                  cout << "" << endl;

                  s.find(w);
                  if ( s.find( w ) != std::string::npos )
                  {
                      cout << w << " was found in the paragraph. " << endl;

                  }
                 else 
                  {
                    cout << w << " was not found in the paragraph. " << endl;
                  }
                 cout << "" << endl;
                 cout <<"Would you like to try another? Y/N \n ";
                        cin >> select2;
                        clearScreen ();
                         if (select2 == 'Y' || select2 == 'y')
                          {
                             printMenu (); 
                             break;
                          }
                          else if (select2 != 'Y' || select2 != 'y')
                              exit(0);



    }


    return 0;
}

//Function prologue
    /*********************************************************************
    * clearScreen ()                                                     *
    * The purpose of this function is to clear the screen!               *
    *********************************************************************/

    //This clears the screen 
    void clearScreen()
    {
        cout << "\33[H\33[2J"; 
        // clears the screen
    }

 //Function prologue 
    /*********************************************************************
    * printMenu()                                                        *
    * The purpose of this function is to print the menu again if         *
    * the user selects Y or y!                                           *
    *********************************************************************/

    void printMenu()
    {
    //Variables 
    string s;
    char selection;
    string w;
    string buf;
    char select2;

    cout << "Enter a paragraph or a sentence : " ; //Get sentence 
    getline(cin, s);



    //Menu 
    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "                 Menu          " << endl;
    cout <<"        ------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "A -- Convert paragraph to all caps " << endl;
    cout << "B -- Convert paragraph to all lowercase " << endl;
    cout << "C -- Delete whitespaces " << endl;
    cout << "D -- Split words & remove duplicates " << endl;
    cout << "E -- Search a certain word " << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Please select one of the above: " ; //Get selection 
    cin >> selection;
    cout << "" << endl;
    stringstream ss(s);// Insert the string into a stream
    vector<string> tokens;// Create vector to hold words 
    switch (selection) //Switch statement
    {
        //If A is chose convert to uppercase 
        case 'a':
        case 'A': cout << "You chose to convert the paragraph to all uppercase" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  for(int i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
                    {
                        s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
                    }
                    cout << "This is it: " << s << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    cout <<"Would you like to try another? Y/N \n ";
                        cin >> select2;
                        clearScreen ();
                         if (select2 == 'Y' || select2 == 'y')
                          {
                             printMenu (); 
                             break;
                          }
                          else if (select2 != 'Y' || select2 != 'y')
                              exit(0);



        case 'b':
        case 'B':
                  //If B is chose convert to lowercase 
                  cout << "You chose to convert the paragragh to all lowercase" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  for (int i=0; s[i] !='\0'; i++)
                  {
                      s[i]=tolower(s[i]);
                  }
                    cout << "This is it: " << s << endl;
                    cout << "" << endl;
                    cout <<"Would you like to try another? Y/N \n ";
                        cin >> select2;
                        clearScreen ();
                         if (select2 == 'Y' || select2 == 'y')
                          {
                             printMenu (); 
                             break;
                          }
                          else if (select2 != 'Y' || select2 != 'y')
                              exit(0);

        case 'c':
        case 'C': 
                  //If C is chosen delete spaces 
                  cout << "You chose to delete the whitespaces in the paragraph" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
                    if(s[i] == ' ') s.erase(i,1);
                  cout <<"This is it: " << s << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  cout <<"Would you like to try another? Y/N \n ";
                        cin >> select2;
                        clearScreen ();
                         if (select2 == 'Y' || select2 == 'y')
                          {
                             printMenu (); 
                             break;
                          }
                          else if (select2 != 'Y' || select2 != 'y')
                              exit(0);
        case 'd':
        case 'D': 
                  //If D is chosen split words and remove duplicates 
                  cout << "You chose to split the words & remove the duplicates in the paragraph" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;

                  while (ss >> buf)
                  {
                    if(find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), buf) == tokens.end())
                    tokens.push_back(buf);
                  }
                  cout << "This is it: " << endl;
                  for (vector<string>::iterator it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it)
                  cout << "- " << *it << " " << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;


                  cout << "" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  cout <<"Would you like to try another? Y/N \n ";
                        cin >> select2;
                        clearScreen ();
                         if (select2 == 'Y' || select2 == 'y')
                          {
                             printMenu (); 
                             break;
                          }
                          else if (select2 != 'Y' || select2 != 'y')
                              exit(0);





        case 'e':
        case 'E': 
                  //If E is chosen allow the user to search for a word 
                  cout << "You chose to search for a certain word in the paragraph. " << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  cout << "Enter the word you want to search for: ";
                  cin >> w;
                  cout << "" << endl;

                  s.find(w);
                  if ( s.find( w ) != std::string::npos )
                  {
                      cout << w << " was found in the paragraph. " << endl;

                  }
                 else 
                  {
                    cout << w << " was not found in the paragraph. " << endl;
                  }
                 cout << "" << endl;
                 cout <<"Would you like to try another? Y/N \n ";
                        cin >> select2;
                        clearScreen ();
                         if (select2 == 'Y' || select2 == 'y')
                          {
                             printMenu (); 
                             break;
                          }
                          else if (select2 != 'Y' || select2 != 'y')
                              exit(0);



    }
    }
```

Comment: better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @qxg Not a candidate. OP wants to know "Why does my program misbehave?" Codereview is for "My code does exactly what I want. How can I make it work better?"

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't your loop and how you're printing each word out, it's how you are removing the duplicates. Inserting each word into a set isn't going to preserve the original order they were input in. The reason your output isn't correct when you print the words out in the loop is because of this line: `tokens.insert(buf);` where tokens as declared as `set<string> tokens;`

You even have a comment that says "Create vector to hold our words" and that is what you should've done because the vector will preserve the order if you just use its ".push_back()" member function along with the "find( )" function to prevent duplicates from being inserted.

How I fixed it:

1. `set<string> tokens;` **->** `vector<string> tokens;`
2. `while (ss >> buf) {
   // check to make sure vector doesn't contain "buf"
   if(find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), buf) == tokens.end())
      tokens.push_back(buf);
   }`

   3. `for(set<string>::iterator it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it)` **->** `for(vector<string>::iterator it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it)`